# django-allauth receiver signal to add group permission to user on signup

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-signals

My goal is to add a new group to a user when they signup. I'm using the django-allauth package and it seems the best way to do this is to use the [package defined signals](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html). Not totally sure how to debug this as I have not been getting any error messages.

signals.py

```
from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

#Group Added To New Users: "Can Add Pattern, Symbol, Broker"

@receiver(user_signed_up)
def user_signed_up_signal_handler(request, user):
    group = Group.objects.get(name='Can Add Pattern, Symbol, Broker')
    user.groups.add(group)
    user.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the fanciest answer but I was able to resolve this issue by putting the exact same code in my models.py file instead of signals.py.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're doing something to load signals.py and not just expecting it be be auto-loaded? If not then the recommendation per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/ is to import signals.py in the app's ready() function.

`/apps/core/__init__.py`

```
default_app_config = 'apps.core.apps.CoreConfig'
```

`/apps/core/apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.core'

    def ready(self):
        import apps.core.signals
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the above answer did work!  Thank you!

I also found that overriding `save_user(...)` in the `DefaultSocialAccountAdaptor` subclass worked nicely, and I went with that.  I've found I needed to have one of these adapters for other things wrt using allauth, so this put all of the changes in one place.

In my `myapp/user_account_adaptor.py`:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
import re

from myapp.constants import STAFF_GROUP_NAME, EMAIL_DOMAIN
from myapp.log import logger


class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    # regular account not relevant to this question, but showing to make the distinction
    pass

class MySocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def populate_user(self, request, sociallogin, data):
        # Runs on each login and initial signup.  Set the username based on the company email, and flag all users as "staff" for the admin interface.
        if data["email"].endswith(f"@{EMAIL_DOMAIN}"):
            data["username"] = re.sub(f'@{EMAIL_DOMAIN}$', '', data["email"])
        else:
            data["username"] = data["email"]
        user = super().populate_user(request, sociallogin, data)
        if user.email.endswith(f"@{EMAIL_DOMAIN}"):
            user.is_staff = True
        return user

    def save_user(self, request, sociallogin, form=None):
        # Runs only the first time a user uses Google for login.
        # Explicitly put users in the default lowest-level permissions group.
        saved_user = super().save_user(request, sociallogin, form)
        logger.info(f"Adding new user {saved_user.email} to group {STAFF_GROUP_NAME}")
        group = Group.objects.get(name=STAFF_GROUP_NAME)
        saved_user.groups.add(group)
        return saved_user
```

In `settings.py`:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTOR = 'myapp.user_account_adaptor.MyAccountAdapter'
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'myapp.user_account_adaptor.MySocialAccountAdapter'
```